# Sql Query : Next Last Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have tables `Customer` and `Calls` like this:

**Customers** table:

- CustomerId : uniqueidentifier
- BusinessName :  nvarchar(MAX)

**Calls** table:

- CallId  : uniqueidentifier
- CallDate :datetime
- CustomerId: uniqueidentifier
- Status: int (call has been answered or no)

I want to get all the customers with last called and next call columns.

`Last Called` is the last call where status = 1. `Next Call` is the call where status = 0 and the `Calldate > now` date. Null if they do not have any. This is a non working example just to show the format

```
Select * 
From Customers,
       Calls.CallId as LastCalledId   
       Calls.CallDate as LastCalledDate
       Calls.CallId as NextCallId
       Calls.CallDate as NextCallDate
LEFT JOIN 
    Calls ON Customers.CustomerId = Calls.CustomerId
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What version of sql server are you working with? Also, can you provide sample data as DDL+DML and desired results?

Comment: 2008. But we may upgrade later if there is easier solution which 2008 doesn't have.  So if you can with 2 ways tell me please.

Comment: I updated. If you need more information tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

**Update**

```
select c.id
, lastcall.calldate
, lastcall.id
, firstcall.calldate
, firstcall.id
from @customers c
outer apply (select top 1 calls.calldate, calls.id from @calls calls where calls.custid = c.id and calldate < getdate() order by calldate desc) lastcall(calldate, id)
outer apply (select top 1 calls.calldate, calls.id from @calls calls where calls.custid = c.id and calldate >= getdate() order by calldate asc) firstcall(calldate, id)
```

original answer:

```
select c.id
, answered.calldate LastCalledDate
, answered.id LastCalledID
, unaswered.calldate NextCalledDate
, unaswered.id NextCalledID
from @customers c
left join @calls answered ON answered.custid = c.id AND status = 1
left join @calls unaswered ON unaswered.custid = c.id AND unaswered.status = 0 and unaswered.calldate > getdate()
```

Comment: this query may return many result. I just want the first one > todays date and last one< todays date

Comment: @MissakBoyajian see the update, still not very clear but I think that's what yu mean.

Comment: I have never used outer apply so give me time to read about that and test it :) Thanks I'll be back

Comment: I am concerned about performance. Is outer apply the best solution or there can be better ones?

Comment: @MissakBoyajian Does the execution plan suggest any indexes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **WHERE** clause in **LEFT JOIN** for getting required data rows.Here you can use  where clause with Calls.status = 0 or 1  (as per your requirement)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **AND** in join query. Then order calls and get last one with limit.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers,
       Calls.CallId as LastCalledId   
       Calls.CallDate as LastCalledDate
       Calls.CallId as NextCallId
LEFT JOIN 
    Calls ON (Customers.CustomerId = Calls.CustomerId AND Calls.Status = 1)
ORDER BY Calls.CallDate DESC
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM Customers,
       Calls.CallId as LastCalledId   
       Calls.CallId as NextCallId
       Calls.CallDate as NextCallDate
LEFT JOIN 
    Calls ON (Customers.CustomerId = Calls.CustomerId AND Calls.Status = 0 AND CallDate > NOW())
ORDER BY Calls.CallDate DESC;
```

Comment: I think the next and Last are the same here

Comment: This returns 1 customer i think

Comment: If you delete TOP 1 you can get all customers. @MissakBoyajian

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide DDL and DML for sample data I couldn't test my answer, so It's not guaranteed to produce the desired results.
Having said that, here is my attempt that should work on versions 2008 or higher.

Using a cte to calculate the last answered call for each customer (assuming calldate is unique) and a couple of left joins I came up with this:

```
;WITH LastCall AS
(
    SELECT  CustomerId,
            CallId,
            CallDate
    FROM Calls t0
    WHERE [Status] = 1
    AND CallDate = 
    (
        SELECT MAX(CallDate)
        FROM Calls t1
        WHERE [Status] = 1
        AND t1.CustomerId = t0.CustomerId
    )
)

SELECT  cu.CustomerId, 
        cu.Name,
        lc.CallId as LastCalledId,
        lc.CallDate as LastCalledDate,
        nc.CallId as NextCallId,
        nc.CallDate as NextCallDate
FROM Customers as cu
LEFT JOIN LastCall lc ON cu.CustomerId = lc.CustomerId 
LEFT JOIN Calls nc ON cu.CustomerId = nc.CustomerId AND nc[Status] = 0 AND nc.CallDate > GETDATE()
```

Please note that for versions 2012 and higher you might be able to use [FIRST_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql) or [LAST_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql) built in functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using different ways :

```
    Select cu.CustomerId,LastCall.Callid,LastCall.calldate,NextCall.Callid,NextCall.calldate from Customers cu,
    (select max(callid) Callid,max(calldate) calldate,CustomerId from Calls c where status = 1 group by CustomerId) LastCall,
    (select max(callid) Callid,max(calldate) calldate,CustomerId from Calls c where status = 0 and calldate > sysdate group by CustomerId) NextCall
    where cu.CustomerId = LastCall.CustomerId and cu.CustomerId = NextCall.CustomerId
    order by 1

Or by replacing in your query :

    Select (select max(callid) from Calls c where c.CustomerId = Cu.CustomerId and status = 1) as LastCalledId,
       (select max(CallDate) from Calls c where c.callid = (select max(callid) from Calls c where c.CustomerId = Cu.CustomerId and status = 1)) as LastCalledDate,
       (select max(callid) from Calls c where c.CustomerId = Cu.CustomerId and status = 0 and CallDate > sysdate ) as NextCallId,
       (select max(CallDate) from Calls c where c.callid = (select max(callid) from Calls c where c.CustomerId = Cu.CustomerId and status = 0 and CallDate > sysdate )) as NextCallDate 
    From Customers Cu,Calls c ON Cu.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
```